# Are Relative pronouns or Relative adverbs Subordinating Conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinators

"**It is a song that my mother taught me**."
This sentence consists of :

(1) *a main clause* : "It is a song".
(2) *a subordinate/dependent clause* : "that my mother taught me".
(3) *A relative pronoun or a Subordinating Conjunction*, **THAT**, connecting those two types of clauses.

**Note** : Here, the word, **THAT**, acts as a **conjunction** by *connecting two clauses* - the main clause (*It is a song*) and the subordinate clause (*that my mother taught me*). And **that** acts as a **pronoun** when *it replaces the noun*, “**song**”.

**Now my question is : " Do the relative pronouns function as both a pronoun and a Subordinating Conjunction simultaneously??**

Comment: No: "that" belong to the word class (part of speech) **subordinator**, and its function is **marker**. It introduces the subordinate relative clause. Btw, the main clause in this instance is the whole sentence, so "that" is not connecting two clauses. "That my mother taught me" is  a subordinate relative clause modifying "song".

Comment: Incidentally, questions like this are very basic. You really ought to ask them on our learners site ELL, see here: [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: No. Your *that* is not connecting two clauses; the relative pronoun is either the subject or the object of its clause (it's the object in yours). The subordinating conjunction connects two clauses; it is neither the subject nor the object of its clause.

Comment: There is a long-standing problem with calling _that_ a relative pronoun. It's not the same kind of thing as _which_ at all, comes from a different source, has a completely different history, and is still growing into its role as a relative pronoun in Modern English. So you can't argue from textbook definitions; this is real language.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "That" introduces the relative clause, a modifier in noun phrase structure. It doesn't connect two clauses but simply marks the relative clause as being subordinate.

Comment: @BillJ: That's what I said: "*that* is not connecting two clauses." Also, I am using the OP's traditional, prescriptive grammar framework (not CGEL's) to explain.

Comment: @TinfoilHat So when you said "the subordinating conjunction connects two clauses", you were talking about non-relatives.

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, non-relatives. The subordinating conjunction — not the relative pronoun — connects. In *My mother taught me a song when I was young*, *when* heads the subordinate clause and connects it to the main clause. The subordinate clause has its own subject, and it's not *when*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In the subordinate clause "when I was young", the head is not "when" but the verb "is. The head of a clause is always a verb. For those who take "when" to be a subordinator, it is simply a marker.

Comment: @BillJ: Again, I am not using CGEL's framework/terminology.

Comment: @BillJ, Is the marker of the subordinate clause (the word which introduces a subordinate clause) called a subordinator?